# SQL comment with array element PHP

Tags: php, sql

This is my first question in this site hope that some one will help me over here.

I have a investor table with some fields and a project table with some files

```
Project table
---------------------
project_investor_id     1,26,29,30,39,48
```

data stored as , separated values 
So in my investor admin area i want show perticular project to show for logedin investor
I am using this function.

```
public function list_all_projects_by_userid ($uid){


    $rs = mysql_query("select * from  project_table WHERE project_investor_id LIKE '$uid'  ORDER BY project_id DESC");    
    $i = 0;
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)) {    
    $result[$i]['project_id'] = $row['project_id'];
    $result[$i]['project_investor_id'] = $row['project_investor_id'];
    $result[$i]['project_name'] = $row['project_name'];
    $result[$i]['project_location'] = $row['project_location'];
    $result[$i]['project_location'] = $row['project_location'];
    $result[$i]['project_phase'] = $row['project_phase'];
    $result[$i]['project_capital'] = $row['project_capital'];
    $result[$i]['project_notes'] = $row['project_notes'];
    $result[$i]['project_file'] = $row['project_file'];
    $i++;
    }
    return $result;
    }
```

But its not working with project have multiple investors.
Please let me know how recode this?

Thank You

Comment: Just a tip, you can squash all that code in the while down to: `$result[] = $row; $i++;`. Oh, and that's incredibly vulnerable to SQL injection

Comment: What is passed in your `$uid`?

Comment: Also you shouldn't use `mysql_*` functions in new code, instead try PDO or MySQLi

Comment: I am passing my current loged user id

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Normally, you should have another mapping table for such things. And use joins to do a search.

If you want to make your approach work, you should change your sql request like this:

```
 $rs = mysql_query("select * from  project_table WHERE project_investor_id LIKE '%$uid%'  ORDER BY project_id DESC");
```

See `%` symbols added before and after `$uid`. It should work fine with that.

Also, remember about sql injections! You must escape your input. with mysql_* you can do it like this:

```
 $rs = mysql_query("select * from  project_table WHERE project_investor_id LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($uid) . "%'  ORDER BY project_id DESC");
```

Function to escape: [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php). Also, read carefully about what is shown in warning section of linked page.

But still, you should better put a list of project investors into a different table. It should be something lie this:

```
Project table
-------------
pr_id    pr_name


project investors map table
----------------------------
pr_id         investor_id
 1              1
 1              26
 1              29
```

And then, your request will be like:

```
$rs = mysql_query("select * from  project_table as pt join project_investor_map  as pi on pi.pr_id = pi.investor_id WHERE pi.investor_id = ".mysql_real_escape_string($uid) . "  ORDER BY project_id DESC");
```

which will take all projects of some investor

Comment: Are you sure the %-way will work? Think of $uid is "1,30" as these are the two uids to find all projects to. Your approach won't select the first row stated in the question, will it?  *EDIT* Just found out $uid only can be one ID, didn't understand it that way - sorry :-)

Comment: I understand your question. It will work in his case (currently logged in user ID), but of course there are problems with multiple values.

Comment: Hi please see $uid only have one ID at a time. It give current loged user id.

Comment: @FAngel this is function of a class. So i think its not easily venerable

Comment: @FAngel yes i have another table for investors and i am using this filed to connect which investors are for this project. The method works. Thank you very much.

Comment: I understand you have that another table for investors, but you should add another table which will connect investors and projects. As a replacement for that field. Reason: currently you will be unable to get easily a project(s) having two or more common investors.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you right, your main problem is your datababse-design.

You should not save multiple investors comma-seperated, instead you should build a n:m-relation (if investors can invest into many projects and many projects can have many investors) from projects to investors (with a "join-table"). That way, such querys would be pretty easy done.

Check out articles referencing "Database normalization" to find out more about good database design. After that, joins and sub-queries will help you to find the right way of doing this.

And in addition, check out articles about sql-injections (if you can't be absolute sure $uid is a number)

Comment: Thank you i will do more research on that ;)